# Android asynctask exception

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

i'm doing an app that have to get an XML file from an url and parse it. I always find this log cat (PS:i can't find the correct google prettify sintax code highlighting):

```
11-06 23:12:44.940: E/Trace(8751): error opening trace file: No such file or directory(2)
11-06 23:12:51.345: E/Error:(8751): expected: /hr read: body (position:END_TAG </body>@6:8 in java.io.StringReader@431887b8) 
11-06 23:12:51.360: E/AndroidRuntime(8751): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-06 23:12:51.360: E/AndroidRuntime(8751): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-06 23:12:51.360: E/AndroidRuntime(8751):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
11-06 23:12:51.360: E/AndroidRuntime(8751):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
11-06 23:12:51.360: E/AndroidRuntime(8751):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
11-06 23:12:51.360: E/AndroidRuntime(8751):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
11-06 23:12:51.360: E/AndroidRuntime(8751):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-06 23:12:51.360: E/AndroidRuntime(8751):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-06 23:12:51.360: E/AndroidRuntime(8751):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-06 23:12:51.360: E/AndroidRuntime(8751):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-06 23:12:51.360: E/AndroidRuntime(8751):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-06 23:12:51.360: E/AndroidRuntime(8751): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-06 23:12:51.360: E/AndroidRuntime(8751):     at com.ambro.app.Update$connection.doInBackground(Update.java:39)
11-06 23:12:51.360: E/AndroidRuntime(8751):     at com.ambro.app.Update$connection.doInBackground(Update.java:1)
11-06 23:12:51.360: E/AndroidRuntime(8751):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-06 23:12:51.360: E/AndroidRuntime(8751):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-06 23:12:51.360: E/AndroidRuntime(8751):     ... 5 more
```

the xml could be found at: http://www.lookedpath.tk/apps/firstapp/version.xml

the update.java code:

```java
public class Update extends Activity {
    private TextView testo2;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.update);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        testo2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    }
    public void goToUpdate (View view) {
        System.out.println("ciao");
        new connection().execute();
    }
    public class connection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
             boolean updated=false;
             String lastversion=null;
             Element e=null;
             final String URL = "http://www.lookedpath.tk/apps/firstapp/version.xml";
             final String VERSION = "version";
             final String APPLICATION = "application";
             XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
             String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
             Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

             NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(APPLICATION);
             for (int i=0;i<nl.getLength();i++) {
                e = (Element) nl.item(0);
                lastversion = parser.getValue(e, VERSION); // name child value
             }

             String actver = getString(R.string.version);
             if(actver==lastversion) updated=true;

             return updated;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean... result) {
            if(result[0]==false){
                testo2.setText(R.string.newversion);
            } else {
                testo2.setText(R.string.nonewversion);
            }

        }

    };

}
```

so this is the xmlparser.java file:

```java
public class XMLParser {
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}

public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
            // return DOM
        return doc;
}
public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
    NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
    return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
}

public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node child;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                     if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         return child.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
  }
}
```

the logcat say that the error is in the line 39 of the update class:

```java
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(APPLICATION);
```

but i can't manage to resolve the problem. can anyone help me?

**UPDATE:**
i have fixed the error 405 but i still have a null pointer exception. i found that the program run correctly but never enter in the post execute method because of this exception..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried your code there is not any problem, it is fine. Problem is in the link.

In browser it looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu>
<application>
<version>1.5</version>
</application>
</menu>
```

But when i print xml variable it give me

```
<html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

and then in dom variable you got null and when you try to find element in nl variable which is null you got error..,.

I tried your code with some other xml feed it works great..,.

Comment: so what do you suggest to do? how can i fix the xml file?

Comment: SORRY, I have no idea. I got """405 errors often arise with the POST method. You may be trying to introduce some kind of input form on the Web site, but not all ISPs allow the POST method necessary to process the form"" FROM   http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html   link.

Comment: i have fixed the error 405 but i still have a null pointer exception. i found that the program run correctly but never enter in the post execute method because of this exception..

Comment: Have you done some change in code because this time i copy paste your code I got the desired result version=1.5

Comment: no i didn't, now the program simply never enter in post execute method. no error showed. i put a println at the end of doinbackground and the message was showed correctly, but if i put it at the start of the postexecutemethod the message doesn't appear in the log

Comment: remove ... from your post execute runs

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

Answer (score 0):

Hey have a look on my [Library](http://code.google.com/p/javaxmlquery/).

You can easily manipulate XML with it ;)

Comment: thanks for the answer but i can't understand how to use your code to parsing my xml :) i'm new about android dev and you're help is really useful

Comment: in your link there are only 4 lines of code.. where can i find the source code and the example.java? in your code you've 
String myXMLDocument = "<foo type='all'><bar id='itsme' /><bar><fooz name='imtheone' /></bar></foo>"; 
but how can i bring that string from the url? maybe i'm a bit confused, hope you can be patient, thanks :)

Comment: There is the source http://code.google.com/p/javaxmlquery/source/browse/trunk/com/utils/xmlparser/

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link for xml parsing from xml.
    http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

In your activity you are developing the `AsyncTask` but you forgot to override `onPreExecute` method. See this example for how to develop `AsyncTask` in your activity.

```
package com.androidhive.jsonparsing;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        new GetEventsTask().execute("");
    }

    protected class GetEventsTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
                AndroidJSONParsingActivity.this);

        //PreExecute Method

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Loading, Please Wait..");
            this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        //doInBackground Method

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
                String... params) {
            contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Making HTTP request
            try {
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
                Log.i("json objects",""+json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
            try {
                // Getting Array of Contacts
                contacts = jObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                    // Phone number is agin JSON Object
                    JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                    String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                    String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                    String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                    map.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    contactList.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return contactList;
        }

        //onPostExecute Method 


        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                    contactList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME,
                            TAG_EMAIL, TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] {
                            R.id.name, R.id.email, R.id.mobile });
            // selecting single ListView item
            ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);



            // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // getting values from selected ListItem
                    String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                    String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
                    String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();

                    // Starting new intent
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
                    startActivity(in);
                }
            });
            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                this.dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: now i override onPreExecute method but the error is still the same. i've used the xml parser you linked and is it that is showing this error

Comment: no,i am not using asny task here. first do the parsing without asyn task if it you get the data from url then you think about asyntask. run this in real device or check your avd internet settings

Answer (score 0):

From the logs, I can see you have a NullPointer in Update.java, line 39. You can start from there. I believe it's not related to AsyncTask.

Comment: i saw that error is in line 39 but i can't understand where's the error. thanks

Comment: NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(APPLICATION);

Comment: have you checked if the xml is valid? it looks like it's not, that's why you're getting null parser.getDomElement()

Comment: i think the xml file is valid and if it isn't i can't find the error:
<menu>
   <application>
       <version>1.5</version>
   </application>
</menu>

Answer (score 0):

you get just null xml at that position so debuge your application first check any xml responce u get or not????

if u get null xml then use following code for parse xml

```
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import android.util.Log;
public class XMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

String elementValue = null;
Boolean elementOn = false;
userdata d = userdata.getInstance();
public static XMLGettersSetters data = null;

public static XMLGettersSetters getXMLData() {
    return data;
}

public static void setXMLData(XMLGettersSetters data) {
    XMLHandler.data = data;
}

/**

 * This will be called when the tags of the XML starts.

 **/

@Override

public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,

        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    elementOn = true;

    if (localName.equals("application"))

    {
        data = new XMLGettersSetters();
    } 

}

/**

 * This will be called when the tags of the XML end.

 **/

@Override

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)

        throws SAXException {

    elementOn = false;

    /**

     * Sets the values after retrieving the values from the XML tags

     * */

    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("version")){

        System.out.println("ststus" + elementValue);

        d.setIsregi(elementValue);


    }

/**

 * This is called to get the tags value

 **/

@Override

public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)

        throws SAXException {

    if (elementOn) {

        elementValue = new String(ch, start, length);

        elementOn = false;

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the correct DTD to your xml (Document Type Definition) , try it and you will see that the parsing will run smooth .
Step 1 : Generate correcte DTD
Step 2 : Add it to your xml file and save it
Step 3 : upload your xml file , parse it and enjoy .